# How to mark directories in the output of the `find` command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

For example, I looking for files and directories in some directory:

```bsh
ubuntu@example:/etc/letsencrypt$ sudo find . -name example.com*
./archive/example.com
./renewal/example.com.conf
./live/example.com
ubuntu@example:/etc/letsencrypt$
```

How can I mark that `./archive/example.com` and `./live/example.com` are directories in the output above?

Comment: You can't say that  the "example.com" in `./archive/example.com` and `./live/example.com` is a directory -although you could say that `./archive` and `./live` are. Do you want to amend your question?

Comment: @JeremyBoden, the answers below are what I need. I don't want to amend my question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Print the file type along with the name with `-printf "%y %p\n"`:

```
$ sudo find . -name 'example.com*' -printf "%y %p\n"
d ./archive/example.com
f ./renewal/example.com.conf
d ./live/example.com
```

The use of `-printf` assumes GNU `find` (the most common `find` implementation on Linux systems).

Answer (score 24):

Find twice:

```bsh
echo 'directories'
find . -name 'example.com*'   -type d

echo 'non-directories'
find . -name 'example.com*' ! -type d
```

Note too the quoting of the pattern used for the name test.  Without quotes, the shell would try to match the string against names in the current directory before calling `find`. If the `failglob` shell option was set in the `bash` shell, or if the `NOMATCH` shell option in `zsh` was not unset, an unquoted globbing pattern that didn't match anything would generate an error from the shell, and `find` would not be called at all.

---

Alternatively, just output a slash at the end of the directory pathnames (this is how `ls -p` would represent directories):

```bsh
find . -name 'example.com*' \( -type d -exec printf '%s/\n' {} \; -o -print \)
```

The above `find` command first tests that the name is correct. If it is, and it's a directory, it calls `printf` to output the pathname of the directory with a slash at the end.  If it's not a directory `-print` is used to just output the pathname as is.

With GNU `find`, the `-exec printf '%s/\n' {} \;` bit could be replaced by `-printf '%p/\n'`.

With standard `find`, you could also use `-exec printf '%s/\n' {} +` to  call the external `printf` utility as few times as possible, but this would mean that directories likely would be outputted last, or at least in batches.

---

Another alternative is to actually use `ls -p` to tell directories apart from other file types.  Using `ls -p`, a directory would be listed with a trailing `/` character, just as above.

```bsh
find . -name 'example.com*' -exec ls -f -d -p {} +
```

I'm using `-f` here to avoid letting `ls` sort the output, and `-d` to avoid listing the *contents* of directories.

You could use `ls -F` instead of `ls -p` to also put *other* marks on file types other than directories. For example, executables would be suffixed by `*` and symbolic links would be suffixed by `@`.

Both `-p` and `-F` (and `-f` and `-d`) are standard options to the `ls` utility.

Comment: This one has the advantage over the accepted answer of working regardless of which `find` implementation you're working with.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `file` like that:

```
sudo find . -name "example.com*" -print0 | xargs  -0 sudo file
```

Example output:

```
$ sudo find .  -name "example.com*"   -print0 | xargs  -0 sudo file
./example.com. big file: ASCII text
./example.com-dir:       directory
./example.com:           empty
```

Answer (score 4):

I would call an `ls` on it:

```
# find . -name example.com\* -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld
```

If you need to do the `find` and `ls` as `root` and you aren't then you could do:

```
# sudo bash -c "find . -name example.com\* -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld"
```

The number of backslashes before the asterisk `*` may depend on your shell - perhaps you need 0 or 1 of them inside the quotes `""`.

Comment: GNU & FreeBSD versions of find (and probably others) have a `-ls` option, so there's no need for xargs (in fact, there's rarely ever a need to pipe find into xargs, `-exec` is built-in to find).  `find . -name 'example.com*' -ls`.   The output is very similar, only slightly different, to running `ls -l`.   Ubuntu, of course, has GNU find.

Comment: @cas Thanks. I wanted to use the `-d` option to `ls` so I suppose I need to call it, or does the built-in `ls` have the same options? I use `xargs` because it is more generic.

Comment: With GNU find / ls you could just do `find . -name 'example.com*' -exec ls -dp {} +` (the `-p` or `--indicator-style=slash` option appends a slash indicator on directories; `-d` prevents descending into them)

Comment: you don't need `-d` with find's `-ls` option. it will only show matched files/dirs, not the contents of dirs (unless those contents match, of course).   try it and see: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -ls`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more portable option that will work with *nix flavors without the gnu `-printf` option (macOS for example) you can add a slash to the end of directory paths via `ls` like so:

`find . -name "example.com*" -exec ls -dF {} \;`

example:

```
$ sudo find . -name "example.com*" -exec ls -dF {} \;
./archive/example.com/
./renewal/example.com.conf
./live/example.com/
```

This also happens to be in a format more suitable for further piping to more unix commands.

Comment: Note that `-F` also adds other characters to other file types (making it hazardous to pipe these into further commands).  I've already mentioned this in my own answer.

Comment: Good point! I missed that part of your answer, thanks for pointing it out.